# CDF for list of numbers

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

I hope that someone can help me with this! I have a list of values as below:

```
82.1134
84.5516
91.1851
65.6035
69.971
92.4706
79.1505
93.0844
92.9598
```

and I need to find the CDF! how can calculate and present that in a chart?

I do appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to CV! The [empirical cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function)? If so, what don't you understand about calculating it?

Comment: In `R`, you can calculate ECDF by calling `ecdf(data)`, where `data` is a vector, consisting of your data values. Please see more details [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf) and [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf).

Comment: Is there a way in which I can do it in excel?

Comment: Undoubtedly you can do it in MS Excel, but if your question is really about that it is off-topic here. See advice in the Help Center about software-related questions. Whatever the software, the recipe is sort the values from smallest to largest, and form the cumulative or running sum of fractions 1/$n$ for sample size $n$. If you want to sort from largest to smallest, that is the reverse or complementary (cumulative) distribution function or survival or survivor function.

Comment: Lina - *what* are the values in your question?

Comment: Creating an ECDF in Excel is discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4561920/2872891).

Answer (score 3):

$\hat{F}(x)$ is simply the proportion of observations $\leq x$.

That proportion only changes at observation values (it's a step-function).

So you count the proportion of observations at or below each data value, and use the fact that the function will be constant until the next data value to obtain the [empirical cdf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function) for any $x$.